# Change oracle apex database user

Tags: oracle-apex-5

How can I change the oracle apex database user ?. Currently apex is configured to username 'db1' Now I want to configure apex to username 'db2'. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you login to Oracle APEX as a developer you login to an Oracle APEX workspace.  This workspace is allow you to develop in a specific database schema (e.g. database user).  If you are a privileged user of Oracle APEX you can associate database schemas with APEX workspaces.  If you do not have access to Oracle APEX instance administration contact your database administrator.

When you create an application your application has a default parsing schema.  To change the default parsing schema of an application:
1. Login to Oracle APEX
2. Click the "Application Builder" icon
3. Click the "Edit Application Properties" button
4. Click the "Security" tab
5. Click the "Database Session" sub tab
6. Change the parsing schema to another schema your workspace has been granted privilege to parse as

[image]